# Изменения текста кнопок "choose file" в Contact Form 7 (wordpress)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, contact-form7

Собственно вопрос в названию. Мне нужно заменить текст кнопок в Contact Form 7 на вордпресе (их значение дает сам браузер) на свои. Вроде как то читал что можно сделать через вкладку  Additional Settings, но как так сделать не нашел

Comment: Вот к примеру здесь же описаны несколько вариантов. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944267/how-to-change-the-button-text-of-input-type-file

Answer (score 0):

Этот код вставляет кнопку с вашим описанием и скрывает оригинальную. 
При нажатии вашей кнопки, нажимается скрытая.

```
<input type="button" value="Описание кнопки" onclick="document.getElementById('file1').click();" />
<style type="text/css">#file1{display:none;}</style>
[file file-694 id:file1]
```